# postgresql Уникальность для двух полей независимо от порядка значений в этих полях

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints, multi-index

Как создать таблицу, чтоб уникальность значений двух столбцов, осуществлялась как слева направо, так и наоборот справа налево?
типа такого

```sql
CREATE TABLE name (
    id      INT     NOT NULL,
    name    VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    name2  VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT unique_name UNIQUE (name2, name) and CONSTRAINT unique_name2 UNIQUE (name, name2)
);
```

Другими словами `'Игорь', 'Иван'` и `'Иван', 'Игорь'` - одно и тоже, и попытка записать второй вариант вызывала бы ошибку уникальности.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, предложенный на основном SO: [Postgresql enforce unique two-way combination of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30036837/), создать уникальный индекс с применением функций `greatest / least` для пары полей:

```sql
CREATE TABLE name ( 
  id INT NOT NULL, 
  name VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
  name2 VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (id) 
);

create unique index idx_both on name(greatest(name,name2), least(name,name2));

insert into name(id, name, name2) values (1, 'Jack', 'Doe');
insert into name(id, name, name2) values (2, 'Doe', 'Jack');
```

результат на SQLFiddle (Postgres 9.6):

```
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "idx_both"
  Detail: Key ((GREATEST(name, name2)), (LEAST(name, name2)))=(Jack, Doe) already exists.
```